# R Matrix::expm(x), x is complex

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to compute the matrix exponential of a matrix M, such that `M = 1i*(pi/2)*Spin_Sx`, where `Spin_Sx` is a matrix with real values. I get the following error:

```
Matrix::expm(M)
Error in expm(Matrix(x)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function'expm': Error in all0(object[lower.tri(object)]) : 
Argument must be numeric-like atomic vector

Spin_Sx <- structure(c(0, 1.22474487139159, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.22474487139159, 
0, 1.58113883008419, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58113883008419, 0, 1.73205080756888, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.73205080756888, 0, 1.73205080756888, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1.73205080756888, 0, 1.58113883008419, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58113883008419, 
0, 1.22474487139159, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.22474487139159, 0), .Dim = c(7L, 
7L))
```

Comment: You can't have told us everything. I just tried with the data you provided (and renaming your `Spin_Sx` to `A`).   `expm(A)` works perfectly well and does not issue any error message at all.

Comment: @Bhas  It is absolutely not the question. OP is trying to calculate exponential of a complex matrix, `M`, derived from `Spin_Sx`.

Comment: Correct. Sorry about that. I should have looked and read more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution with a little help from my friend. Since, `Spin_Sx` is a symmetric matrix (real or complex), it can be diagonalized as: Spin_Sx = UDU', where U is a unitary matrix, D is a diagonal matrix, and UU' = I. Therefore, exp(Spin_Sx) = U exp(D) U'. As D is a diagonal matrix, the exp(D) is simply the element exponential of the diagonal elements of D.

```
> A <- 1i*(pi/2)*Spin_Sx
> eig_Values <- eigen(A)$values
> Diagonal_A <- diag(exp(eig_Values))
> eig_Vector <- eigen(A)$vector
> expm_A <- eig_Vector %*% Diagonal_A %*% t(Conj(eig_Vector))
```